# What are the 10 sammādiṭṭhis, ten right views?

Tags: abhidhamma, right-view

Maybe a challenging questions for the scholars and literary Abhidhamma-fans, with much possibilities for great merits:

- What are the 10 sammādiṭṭhis, ten right views?

Deatal explaining of each would be a great gift of the deathlessness.

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other low wordily gains by means of trade and exchange.]*

Answer (score 1):

Extracted from [Ten Bases of Meritorious Actions (Ten Punnakiriya-vatthus)](http://aristeinhk.blogspot.com/2015/10/ten-bases-of-meritorious-actions-ten.html?m=1):

> 1. There is a good result in an act of alms-giving, charity giving.
> 2. There is benefit in veneration.
> 3. There is benefit in offering gifts.
> 4. There is the Law of Karma and Its Results which teaches that moral and immoral deeds have respective consequences, in this life and the next.
> 5. There is benefit in tending and supporting one’s own mother, while neglecting her means an evil deed.
> 6. There is benefit in tending and supporting one’s own father, while neglecting him means an evil deed.
> 7. There are unseen worlds of hell, hungry ghosts, demons, devas, Sakkas and brahmas. Existence of such beings should be accepted as a fact.
> 8. There is this present world.
> 9. There is the next world or lives to come.
> 10. There are holy persons who have subdued their thought, word and deed. There are persons with jhanic insight or concentration who see this world and the next clearly. They teach such sights, views and visions in a correct way. We should have confidence in such samanas and brahmanas.

Comment: This is puthujjana samma ditthi from MN 117: https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html

Comment: @Dhammadhatu What is that supposed to mean? It's right view for anyone, isn't it? This isn't what the OP was referring to?  I wonder if someone is reacting to #7 because I didn't' make this up and what was I supposed to do, leave it out?  This is either the right answer or it's not, I don't understand how I could be both voted up and voted down by a sane system.  The truth MATTERS but this system has leaves THE TRUTH to a schizophrenic democratic process. If this is the wrong answer then I will delete it, it's that simple.

Comment: That, the answer, is a good and proper approach, deriving from right view, Sadhu!

Answer (score -1):

There are two levels of Samma Ditthi (right view). One is the puthujjana (ordinary life) samma ditthi and the other is the [lokuttara](https://suttacentral.net/define/lokuttara) samma ditthi (with direct aim to realize Nibbana i.e. understanding the Four Noble Truths). First we have to begin with practising the puthujjana samma ditthi to shed the more coarse defilements of the mind, and then we can more easily make progress with the lokuttara samma ditthi (understanding of the Four Noble Truths).
May you realize Nibbana!
Sadhu!